# Onclick event and redirect to the home page in php

Tags: php, events, redirect, onclick

I have a form, and i want to redirect after update. I using this code, but it doesn't work:

```
<input type=button onClick="calendar.update(<?php echo $info['id']; ?>); location.href='index.php';" value='Save'>
```

How can i add multiple events (include redirect script) for this?

Comment: please share calendar.update(<?php echo $info['id']; ?>);

Comment: you can write location.href='index.php'; in  calendar.update function

Comment: share your update function

Comment: Thaks for your help, i added `document.location.href = 'index.php';` to the _calendar.update_ function.